# Cannot insert into Wordpress database table from custom page

Tags: database, wordpress, insert

I created a custom page with a form and a new table in my wordpress database `wp_applicants`. When I submit, it returns the resultant echo message but does not insert into my database table. Kindly assist.

The code:

```
<?php
    /**
     *Template Name: Career Temp
     */
    get_header(); 
?>

<div class="page-header-wrap">
    <header class="page-header">
        <h1 class="page-header-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>
</div>
<div id="primary" class="content-area span_16 col clr clr-margin">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <!-- paul removed post loop -->
        <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                global $wpdb;
                $fname=$_POST['txt_fname'];
                $lname=$_POST['txt_lname'];
                $tbl="wp_applicants";
                $others= $_POST['txt_email'];
                $wpdb->insert('wp_applicants', array('first_name' => $fname, 'last_name' => $lname, 'email' => $others), array('%s', '%s', '%s'));
                $msg = "Data Submited"; 
                echo $msg;
            }
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            first name - <input type="text" name="txt_fname"/>
            last name - <input type="text" name="txt_lname"/>
            email - <input type="text" name="txt_email"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The code looks correct, check the tablename or fields

Answer (score 1):

Try showing errors, as described in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors).  Something like:

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->insert('wp_applicants', array('first_name' => $fname, 'last_name' => $lname, 'email' => $others), array('%s', '%s', '%s'));
$wpdb->print_error();
$wpdb->hide_errors();
```

Comment: Great!! Problem solved. the print or show error function revealed the wrong field placement in the code. Thanks guys

Comment: Glad to help.  The way to show appreciation around here is to accept the answer (clicking the check mark beside the answer), and/or clicking the upvote button.  Welcome to stackoverflow!